# XMPP and Android

Tags: android, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

I am trying to build a small XMPP client in Android. Any ideas on what library I can use?
I have tried using the Smack API, but there are some issues with it, which makes it not practical.

Comment: The duplicate in question is newer, I closed this in favor of that due to the quality of answers on the newer question (and it has an OP that is actually still a user)

Answer (score 10):

ASmack is port of Smack to Android:

http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

Answer (score 8):

it's already been implemented.
take a look here:
http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

Smack has been ported to Android and works fine now. Nevertheless, if you are looking for a rocket proof port of Smack for Android which supports most of the XMPP extensions (including pubsub) as well as automatic reconnection and other features, you should consider this commercial solution: http://www.ubikod.com/products.htm