# Android: asmack(ported) or smack(patched)?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have searched alot on google and in here to find the best featured API for XMPP client.

I have found the following two:

asmack: .http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

patched smack: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

I cant find any comparison of these two APIs on the internet, so maybe you can help me in which one to choose.?

In the original article of the patched smack he inform that TLS does not work (thats fine I should not use that) I consume that the rest works.
On the other hand asmack is very popular but when I read around the net it seems that it is a little more buggy?

What do you advise me to choose?

Thanks!

Comment: I am also concerned with this problem.
I am now pretty sure that asmack is buggy. I tried it and get lots of problems. I google and I am here. I will try the other way, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asmack is almost the same code as smack, basically what they did is some code refactoring, add some extra methods to extension, changed package order, also they replace DNS class and classes related with Sasl and authentication.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0a8a0fb16752ba52/631dcf2137e79e7f?lnk=raot&pli=1

If you use asmack you wont have major problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend to Avoid asmack In our last project we faced so many problems due open issues :
http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/list
other alternatives are avilable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5487854/771300

Comment: I'd say that aSmack on googlecode is dead and that most of the issues reported there can be fixed, it isn't just documented properly. +1 for linking **[Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions/5487854#5487854)** :)

Comment: the existence of the library on google code without any hint that Is not maintained  any more really create so many problems to many many developers I wish If any one know the developer communicate the developer do so
by the way I do more references in other post related it was really great post