# Implementaion of XMPP into android

Tags: android, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

anyone can tell me about the implementation of XMPP into android. How to start and from which point i can start. please share with me any helpful link or  code snippets for this.

Answer (score 5):

I would look into using the Smack xmpp client library. It's written in java and integrates nicely with the Openfire xmpp server. The Ignite Realtime website which has created both the library and the server have a very active forum and user community. The server is also written in java and you can write custom plugins as well. Here is the website:

[Smack Client API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/)

You can get to the forums and Openfire server on the site menu. I found an open source Smack Android client as well:

[open source Android xmpp client](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)

This is probably a good starting point for creating your own app. The smack library can also be used to connect to Google Talk.

Another route would be to use the javascript Strophe client library in a web view. This is a very robust library that has been around for a while.

[Strophe javascript xmpp client library](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/)

Comment: by using smack library, i am successfully build my application.

Comment: but now i want to transfer file also with chat to other user. please tell me any thing to properly implement this task. waiting for your quick positive reply. :-)

Comment: Hey is it Possible to create the Chatting application for android if we dont have any server ?

Comment: no, it is never-ever possible. you must have an chat server for any android chat application.

Comment: @nickfox  can you tell me, how can we access archived chat messages from server, with the help of smack library. i am working too much on this side, but unable to get exact api from smack library, which will return me archived messages from server. looking forward at your side, to know the solution of this problem.