# how to implement bootstrap peer and SBC for Sip2peer, for Android?

Tags: android, bootstrapping, peer

I have to make an android app that should communicaticate peer to peer. After searching over internet I found one solution is Sip2peer http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer/ but I am not able to implement Bootstrap peer and SBC.

Is there any one who has implemented all this, please provide me steps to implement these stuff.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Pawan

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on 'but I am not able to implement Bootstrap peer and SBC.'?

Comment: also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions

Comment: Yes, It means I need tad more elaboration how to implement Bootstrap peer and SBC application on a public IP. As per my thoughts it requires core java skills but I have only knowledge of j2me and android.. :( Hence need step by step tutorial.

Comment: 'implement'? I think that bit has been done for you. I think the word you are looking for is 'grok'. Good luck.

Comment: @Tom whatever it is.. but now its working fine. Promblem was firewall over LAN and PAN.Then I Have tested on seprate machine, now its working perfectly. Thanks to Marco(Developer & Designer of Sip2peer) who helped me alot.

Comment: Excellent. Pleased to hear :) Are you saying you needed to have your peers on separate machines? Could you explain a little more as I am thinking of using this library and it would be nice to know the gotchas in advance.

Comment: Hi Tom, yes using Sip2peer your peer can be anywhere in world. But you need to run you SBC and Bootstrap peer on public IP and make sure your firewall is properly congiured otherwise it won't allow to listen msgs on SBC and Bootstrap ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run your SBC and Bootstrap peer on public IP. Source code for is already availabe on [Sip2Peer](http://code.google.com/p/sip2peer) . you just need to run SBC and Bootstrap peer code using Ant.

For Android also source code is availabe. Just you need to run it in eclipse then apk will be installes in your device.

NOTE: Run SBC and Bootstrap on Public IP so that it can be reachable from anywhere in the world. 
     And Properly check your firewall settings, that was main issue when I was using it.