# Why can't I connect to the openfire server?

Tags: java, openfire, smack

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to connect to Openfire (which I've installed on my computer) while using Smack.

```
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("shin-pc" ,5222);
    config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true); 
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);             
    connection.connect();
    connection.login("test", "test");
```

When I try debugging or running, there's an error of some sort in the `connect()` line.

*XMPPError connecting to localhost:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to localhost:5222. -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied.*

I've tried switching the host name to "localhost", and it didn't work either.

I have no experience in this XMPP business so I guess it's a common newbie problem or something of the sort...

What might be the problem? How can I fix this so the connection will be successful?

Comment: Edit your question to include the exact error.

Comment: When it reaches the "connect()" line it goes back to the "catch exception" line, It doesn't mention any specific error, How can I check what's the exact error?

Comment: If it's catching an exception, please add a print statement to print the exception to the console, then add the exception to your question above. It's really impossible to help without knowing what your error is, the code above looks ok to me

Comment: Also please check that openfire is really running on your computer, as it doesn't just start by itself and that may be why you can't connect: make sure you can access the console for example.

Comment: aha! XMPPError connecting to localhost:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to localhost:5222. -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied.
I've got into the admin console, so I know the server is running...

Comment: are you running on Windows/Linux/MacOS? maybe your problem is that you are running openfire and the project using smack with two different users and so permission denied (just a theory, never had this problem). Can you try to login to the server using the same account that you used to install openfire? if it is, then try also to connect with an IM client such as Pidgin and see wether it works or not

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it, the XMPPConnection doesn't get to the login line, and also I did create a new user in the server, u: test p: test. so I don't think that's the problem...

Comment: And the computer on which I've installed  the server is running on Windows 7

Comment: Did you create "test" account ?

Comment: @vsm: the account has nothing to do with it, it fails at the connect() - therefore no need for a login+password

Comment: @Bar: I wasn't talking about the user test, but user as in windows user in your case. You could have installed openfire using a different account, or maybe your account is not an admin account. I use MacOS so don't have this problem but you might have access denied because you don't have the rights to connect to openfire without being an admin. As I said, try connecting with Pidgin (and make sure you run everything as admin)

Comment: I've downloaded pidgin... and I was able to log in to the server (with the test account I've created) whether or not I ran pidgin "as administrator" . I also tried running eclipse as an administrator, but that didn't help, and I'm still can't get past the connect() line.     but this is progress nevertheless! what should I check next?

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 5):

I just created a new project in which I need XMPP, and ran into the same problem. However, I realized that it was simply because I had forgotten to add the internet permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Make sure that you haven't done the same mistake.

Comment: can you pls see the problem and tell any solution?
I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ)

Answer (score 3):

I have Same problem .... but i resolved this issue at my end using following steps :::

1) Firstly checked Internet permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

2) Then open the openfire.xml file from C:\Openfire\conf (Installation directory) and edit the file

```
    <network>
        <interface>Your IP Address(192.168.0.1)</interface>
    </network>
```

and save the file and start the openfire server.
        I think it will be helpful for you....

Comment: its saying we cannot save the file by making changes

Comment: bro can you [join](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68853/room-for-devil-and-mar-java) this group n help me in solving problem

Comment: I am using this [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/36CSHhtnaEVDUrgqnWMzqW7) to connect to xmpp and i am getting [exception](http://paste.ofcode.org/3b9wT5yeuLB97rfZgZ7eFEZ)

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, i followed these steps to solve it:

1. disable your firewall first
2. use your the IP address of your server openfire

Answer (score 0):

Use host as localhost if you are using a device.
If you are using an emulator, use ip address (192.168.1.2 or whatever) in the configuration step (line 1 of the given code)