# Chatting application Android

Tags: java, android, xml, chat

I'm on developing an android application which allows users to chat I created an interface and its code for chatting ..

but I don't know how can I make this interface shared for each contact and how can I show his conversations ??

thanks in advance ...

Comment: This question will not get answered unless you give specifics of what you are struggling with. For example I am getting a error when sending a message over the network with the error xyz. Without detail people wont be able to answer.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736861/android-smack-chat-client

Comment: You should look into this a little more yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to elaborate some more to get a better answer. Try to be as specific as possible. i.e. what technology do you intend to use to make the connection between two chatters?

There is a nice example in the SDK that implements a bluetooth chat client

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

I'd definitely dig in to that some if I were you. Even if you aren't wanting the connection to be made via bluetooth it should give you some insight on how to hook up the incomming and outgoing chat messages to the Views on the screen