# Asmack alternative

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

Using Asmack precompiled lib i noticed my app inphone storage use increased a lot. (about 2mb and cannot be transfered to the sd card). Using the source code instead of precompiled lib will reduce the storage need? Is there any other alternative to asmack(and i don't mean smack).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using the source code will reduce the storage need. Do you have any evidence that this is caused by asmack?

As far as I can tell, smack is the only java XMPP library and asmack is the only port for Android so far. See also [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions/5487854#5487854).

BTW using the asmack build environment will also produce a zip archive with the asmack sources.

Comment: " Do you have any evidence that this is caused by asmack?" yes when i don't use asmack ( not using any libraries size is reduced)

Answer (score 0):

You could try pure facebook SDK (chat API) or something similar for another internet resources.

Comment: i don't want it for facebook. I want it for personal XMPP communication

Comment: Ok, you could learn xmpp protocol and work with java sockets without any third party libs...

Comment: well then I would ask a different question , or are you sure that there is no alternative , or including the code library will not help at all.