# XMPP with Android

Tags: android, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

I've started prototyping a multiplayer Android game using HTTP + C2DM push, but now having had a chance to reflect more on the design, I think XMPP would be a much better fit for what i'm trying to build.

I was looking around and couldn't find a great deal of recent information for XMPP on Android, does anyone have any experience or recommended libraries? For what it's worth, this would be client-server over the internet, not near field communication

Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made good experience with [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) as a XMPP-library for Java. People also have used it successfully with Android.

For more alternatives, [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) has an extensive list.