# using XMPP with a .net server and android client

Tags: android, .net, web-services, xmpp, chat

I have an android application (created in eclipse with java) that talks to webservices on a windows 2008 server using .net webservices.  I am very interested in using XMPP for the chat portion of the app, but have not a clue how to implement this.  Can someone help me with implementing the XMPP piece on the above server, as well as the client piece in the android app.  I am basically looking for a step by step walk through (to include what server side software and client side software needed) as I have NEVER used XMPP and really need to finish this app.

Thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions

Comment: This does not give the server piece nor the step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1) Find a server.*

There are several XMPP servers available if you go to the XMPP site and check their handy [list](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers).

Personally, I'm using **OpenFire** and find it super easy to set up and use. Install, run it, and follow the setup wizard.  I would not recommend trying to write your own XMPP server functionality into your own code as it gets complicated quickly. You can easily run a chat server side by side with your web services and have the app on the Client end communicate with both. This still serves up a seamless interface to the user.

*2) Find a library for XMPP development on Android.*

**aSmack** is pretty much what most Android devs use for this. (Info, plus link to code can be found [here](http://metajack.im/2010/02/10/xmpp-library-for-android-developers/).)  If you need more step-by-step help on how to develop this for the Android, I'd suggest searching for/posting more specific questions regarding how to use the library.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Additional Thought: If you require that the Android client only communicate to the server via your web services, you can use the [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) library in your web service code to interact with the chat server.

Comment: ok I am going to mark this as answered.  I appreciate all of the help.