# Google Talk API integrations with Android app

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I am checking out the google talk api's and it uses XMPP.

Here http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview.html#Sending_Chat_Messages

I am reading on integrating it into my android app. Does anyone know of any good tutorials on using Google talk API with android?

Also does it require app-engine to be integrated?

Comment: I use python app engine for google chat to android, but I don't intercept the chat messages so they just appear as any other chat messages on the phone side - is that what you mean ? 

What messages are you after - are they application -> server messages that need to have a level of deliverability ?

App Engine does not have to be "integrated", they are completely stand alone.

Comment: @coder_For_Life22 I wish to do something similar. Did you get it working? Is it possible to send an IM or make a regular phone call to a NON-XMPP user? I would like my google talk number to be displayed on caller ID instead of my real phone number when the app makes the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is [XMPP on Android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions) You can then use GTalk as any other XMPP Server, **but make sure to specify the full JID (e.g. "user@gmail.com") as login name.**