# Develop Google Talk in android

Tags: android, google-talk

I am new to android platform. I want to develop android application with Google Talk. How can I find document related to Google Talk for android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For gtalk can try this [word-press](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/) article

may helpful This android application aims at enabling you to control your phone through gtalk. It can be useful for those who prefer typing sms on a real keyboard.

here is [TalkMyPhone](http://code.google.com/p/talkmyphone/) example app

[Google Talk API integrations with Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304136/google-talk-api-integrations-with-android-app)

Comment: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/12/30/using-google-talk-from-java-example/

Comment: Thank you Dheeresh Singh for your answer. What I really want is that, sample code in Android or tutorial document that let me sign in and get list of contact, can chat and video...