# Android Jabber (XMPP) client

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I am developing Chat application in android. Now server is ready.And i want to connect android  application with server using XMPP (Jabber).
I have follwing information -

Host : 108.167.167.22
User : user1@skyc
password : 111111
port : 5222 / 5280

How can i implement from android ?

Is there any app available in market which has similar functionality(i mean i can connect to server and chat with that application just to test) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

There's an XMPP client available for testing [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/). The apk and the source code are available for download [here](http://people.apache.org/~dims/android/XMPPClient-2.zip). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4769020/1007273) is a thread that describes currently available solutions.

Comment: Thanks for providing source as a help