# Android xmpp library

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I want to make a chat application in android. Most of them suggest smack/asmack library. Apart from smack what is available, as the smack library is unstable?

Comment: smack library is unstable, is it? Gmail using it.

Comment: ha ha ah i can actually imagine expression on your face. "smack library is unstable, Really I didn't know that". +1 for that.

Comment: OMG I am also using smack & nobody told me this..

Comment: Care to elaborate on your statement?

Comment: @hotveryspicy Sorry, what makes you think Google uses Smack?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769020/194894

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have problems with Smack, make sure you have tried aSmack, particularly [this version](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) (it has had some substantial improvements made, the original appears to no longer be maintained).

If you have problems with "stability", asking about those as separate questions is possibly worthwhile (if you haven't already).

Finally though, I know of at least one Java library that could be made to run on Andoid, [Stroke](http://swift.im/git/stroke). It's early days for it, and I believe it doesn't yet have a DNS library that works on Android, but it would be possible to link it up with one that does. It is written from the ground up to match the latest [XMPP specifications](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/) by [developers](http://swift.im/about/) who actively participate in the development of those specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that aSmack is unstable. It [is](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.gtalksms) [used](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beem.project.beem) [by](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yaxim.androidclient) [various](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.otr.app.im) [Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android). Just to name a few.

As a general rule of thumb: If you can't find a library listed for your platform [on the XSF library list](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), then there is likely none.