# Android XMPP via SMACK item-not-found

Tags: android, exception, xmpp

I've got the following problem:

I've created an LeafNode named `TestNode1`. When I try to get this node with `mgr.getNode("TestNode1")` xmpp throws an Exception `item-not-found` and I don't know why.

The Node is created!

If I try the same thing via PC and java...there is no problem and I find the node.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: If you are really using vanilla smack then you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769020/194894

Comment: I have got the same issue , after a while if i fire a request again then the item found , i don't know why such behavior is there

Answer (score -1):

If your doing XMPP on Android you should use

[aSMACK](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) and not [SMACK](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/), herein lies your issue

Comment: Thats it down vote on the generic answer which is trying to help when the question is so generic 1001 things could be the problem. Explain yourself fully! Add some demo code that can explain your problem and we wouldn't be in this situation