# How to send text message in android via sip

Tags: java, android, eclipse, voip

I am developing a application in android in which I want to send text message using sip/xmpp(session initiation protocol) can anyone give me code for it and any guidelines about its development and testing on any free sip provider.

Comment: Why is SIP a requirement? Is it just that you want to send a text message without using the carrier? If that is the case you may want to look at SMSIfied [http://smsified.com/] which allows you to send and receive text messages via a REST API.  It is free while it is in Beta and when it goes live it will be 1 cent per message.

Comment: @User1479880 do you get Send textmessage via sip

Answer (score -1):

**Update having re-read**
Sorry, I failed to realise that the question related only to text messaging. SIP itself doesn't support text messaging, SIMPLE or MSRP extensions enable that. You need to find a stack that you are happy working with, here is one example [Doubango](http://doubango.org/) and their demo product [IMSDroid](https://code.google.com/p/imsdroid/) but Google 'Android MSRP' for plenty of other options. I still don't know anything about XMPP,but check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions) for a great list of libraries and uses.
**End update**

What have you tried so far? For the SIP (voice) part of your question here is the documentation on the [Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html) with all you need to know and here is a free SIP provider: [Getonsip](https://www.getonsip.com/).

*Reduced code sample, largely lifted from Android developer site.*

Essentially you need to make sure minSDK is set to 9 as the SIP library was not added until 2.3. Add the services to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
```

Optionally add the `uses-feature voip` directive if you want your app to not install on devices where it will not work.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" />
```

Create a SipManager:

```
android.net.sip.SipManager manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
```

Create a profile with which to make/receive calls through your provider:

```
android.net.sip.SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
android.net.sip.SipProfile sipProfile = builder.build();
```

If all you care about is making calls:

```
manager.open(profile);
```

To make a call you u work with a listener:

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        call.startAudio();
        call.setSpeakerMode(true);
        call.toggleMute();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
        // Do something.
    }
};
```

Now, as long as you have the SIP address of your peer you can use:

```
SipProfile friendProfile = ...;
manager.makeAudioCall(sipProfile.getUriString(), friendAddress, listener, 30);
```

That should get you started. Unfortunately I have no experience with XMPP.

Comment: Heading clearly tells SIP for text messaging and you have answered for voice calls over SIP.

Comment: Please share android Send Text Message code for sip server...??