# Android xmpp chat

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I need to do a little in app chat for Android application. I'm using the aSmack lib, and I can get that working good.
Here's my problem, I need to be able to switch to other bits of my app, but still receive and store new messages and get notified.

What is the best way to do this ?

I've had a look at the Service class but don't really get if it's what I need.

EDIT: also I can have more than one chat open at a time so when I'm talking to somone, messages to from the others must be saved too.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions/5487854#5487854

Comment: Thanks, but I already have a working solution, my problem is more a design problem.

Comment: I suggested looking at the source code of the Apps that use aSmack, to see how they are designed.

Comment: Finaly what I do and it seems to work is:
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> list_chat;
I create this in the first Avtivity of my app, but I'm still not sure it's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Implement packet listener on service and store the messages in local database.After storing it in database send a broadcast message. Now you can receive it in any activity to show on UI.