# XMPP in Google App Engine and Android for a chat application

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, xmpp

I want to build a simple chat app where users can send messages to each other.
Can I do it with XMPP service from Google App Engine?

In their tutorials and all the tutorials I found on the web it was an implementation of a bot server. I also found similar tutorials but they are in python.

Is there a good and full tutorial that can guide in server and client side?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use XMPP/Smack library available as a third party library. With this you can create you own custom chat application same like the one's available in the market.

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorial that will guide me to do this. Do you know any? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions might help you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Channel API if you want to build your own chat app.  That's for sending messages to browers.

The XMPP API is for sending messages to XMPP clients.  ie if you want to send a message to the chat client that's built into gmail, or a gchat client, or facebook chat.