# How to connect to xmpp server other than gtalk?

Tags: android, xmpp

I'm trying to create an Android XMPP client. I've successfully tested it by connecting with GTalk but now I'm trying to connect to other free servers like Jabber but really confused because connecting to GTalk I could simply write

```
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(talk.google.com, 5222, gmail.com);---
```

But the procedure looks really different for other servers. Where am I stuck now?

for trying other server I registered to https://register.jabber.org/ but think I have misunderstood xmpp.

Comment: No one really knows, unless you show some code or share what XMPP libary you are using.

Comment: That's my code of connection class but ,I just wanted to know weather I can connect to other server in same manner or not, I mean they are not providing host-name,port and service.

Comment: XMPP is a standard protocol, so it should work. You do need to know what server to connect though, so you should find out. Or run your own test server and use that for development. Again, share more details if want better answers.

Comment: I have finally figured out that my code lacks SSL sot its connection are being rejected where can I learn how to do that or is there a simple example of it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'lacks SSL'. If you are missing the needed certificates you can add them to a custom trustore. If you are lacking SSL support, you might need to revise your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) something like [here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)

Comment: yes I am using asmack as well ,                                   These are my imports                                            import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;

Comment: I wouldn't recommend asmack from googlecode, the project has been dead since years. Instead, [have a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) are the different libraries for XMPP

For java (android), you can use following:

- [Echomine Feridian](http://freecode.com/projects/feridian)
- [Jabber Stream Objects (JSO)](http://java.net/projects/jso/)
- [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp)

Comment: I don't find anywhere he want to find some libraries for XMPP.