# Sending files with asmack (or any alternatives)

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I'm trying to send a file with `asmack` with the following:

```
// mConn is an XMPPConnection
FileTransferManager  manager = new FileTransferManager(mConn);
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("operator@domain.corp");
transfer.sendFile(new File(fname), "File for the operator");
```

I'm receiving no exception but in the smack log I can see

```
<error type="cancel" code="501"><feature-not-implemented...
```

Does anyone know what can be the root of the problem?

Since `asmack` hasn't been updated for a while maybe there are any alternatives to it?

Comment: asmack alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions

Comment: You can go for this answer :

[How to transfer files via smack_4.1 library][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889666/how-to-send-file-between-device-using-xmpp-while-chat?noredirect=1#comment47906486_29889666

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. Instead of

```
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("operator@domain.corp");
```

Now I Use

```
String to = mConn.getRoster().getPresence("operator@domain.corp").getFrom();
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(to);
```

and it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize following.

```
pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());

pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());
```

Normally we call the following method to initialize the providers.

```
public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {

    // Private Data Storage
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",
            new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

    // Time
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time",
                    Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w("TestClient",
                "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
    }

    // Roster Exchange
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster",
            new RosterExchangeProvider());

    // Message Events
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event",
            new MessageEventProvider());

    // Chat State
    pm.addExtensionProvider("active",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("composing",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("paused",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("gone",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates",
            new ChatStateExtension.Provider());

    // XHTML
    pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im",
            new XHTMLExtensionProvider());

    // Group Chat Invitations
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference",
            new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());

    // Service Discovery # Items
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items",
            new DiscoverItemsProvider());

    // Service Discovery # Info
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info",
            new DiscoverInfoProvider());

    // Data Forms
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());

    // MUC User
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user",
            new MUCUserProvider());

    // MUC Admin
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin",
            new MUCAdminProvider());

    // MUC Owner
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner",
            new MUCOwnerProvider());

    // Delayed Delivery
    pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay",
            new DelayInformationProvider());

    // Version
    try {
        pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version",
                Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Not sure what's happening here.
    }

    // VCard
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());

    // Offline Message Requests
    pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());

    // Offline Message Indicator
    pm.addExtensionProvider("offline",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline",
            new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());

    // Last Activity
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());

    // User Search
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());

    // SharedGroupsInfo
    pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup",
            "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup",
            new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());

    // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
    pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/address",
            new MultipleAddressesProvider());

    // FileTransfer
    pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si",
            new StreamInitiationProvider());

    pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams",
            new BytestreamsProvider());

    // Privacy
    pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
    pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
    pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired",
            "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands",
            new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());
}
```

Call this method as

> configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());

before creating the XMPPConnection. For further references use this link.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/index.html

Comment: Doesn't help... I've been reading about replacing the path to smack.providers file in ProviderManager.java but can't figure out exactly how. I mean, I did so and seems it doesn't help either. Do I need to do that?