# How to send file between device using xmpp while chat

Tags: android, asmack

Thanks for paying attention over the question...

I am making a XMPP chat application with the help of ejabbered and asmack_4.1 library.

I have installed a PSI client for windows to chat with the android device.
I am able to perform text chat between devices.
I am also able to send file from device to PSI client and PSI client to android device.
But the problem is to send files device to device.

I am using below code to send and receive files :

File send :

```
public void fileTransfer(String filenameWithPath, Bitmap thumbnail, String userId) {
        // FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
        FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        //    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer("usre2@myHost/Smack");
        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(userId + "/Admin"); // "/Good" depends on server
//        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(userId + "/Directors-iMac");

        File file = new File(filenameWithPath);
        try {
            transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!transfer.isDone()) {
            if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
            } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                    || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
                || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)) {
            System.out.println("refused cancelled error " + transfer.getError());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
    }
```

File Receiving :

```
public void fileReciever(AbstractXMPPConnection connection) {
        //**************************************

        // Create the file transfer manager
        final FileTransferManager managerListner = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        //    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
        FileTransferNegotiator negotiator = FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(connection);

        Log.i("File transfere manager", "created");

        // Create the listener
        managerListner
                .addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {

                        Log.i("Recieve File", "new file transfere request  new file transfere request   new file transfere request");

                        Log.i("file request", "from" + request.getRequestor());

                        IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();

                        Log.i(RECIEVE_FILE_ALERT_DIALOG, "accepted");

                        try {

                            transfer.recieveFile(new File("/sdcard/" + request.getFileName()));

                            while (!transfer.isDone() || (transfer.getProgress() < 1)) {

                                Log.i(RECIEVE_FILE_ALERT_DIALOG, "still receiving : " + (transfer.getProgress()) + " status " + transfer.getStatus());

                                if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                                    // Log.i("Error file",
                                    // transfer.getError().getMessage());
                                    Log.i("Recieve File",
                                            "cancelling still receiving : "
                                                    + (transfer.getProgress())
                                                    + " status "
                                                    + transfer.getStatus());
                                    transfer.cancel();

                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        } /*catch (XMPPException e) {

                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }*/ catch (SmackException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

        //**************************************
    }
```

Note : In fileTransfer() method, I am using below line:

```
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(userId + "/Admin"); // "/Good" depends on server
```

I am able to send files from Android device to PSI desktop application and vice versa but i am not able to transfer files between android devices.

Comment: Well you forgot to tell what doesnot work. Or if there are errors or exceptions.

Comment: You let me check for your updates? Please tell the things i asked for. Very unclear all.

Comment: I am able to send files from Android device to PSI desktop application and vice versa but i am not able to transfer files between android devices.

Comment: Yes. That you told before. That was clear from the beginning. Why do you think that repeatedly bringing the same info would help?

Comment: I have written a code to send and receive file for Android, Is that OK..?
And when I send file from android device, it is successfully received over PSI desktop app and when I send file from PSI desktop client, then it is successfully received on Android device. It means the code I wrote for send and receive files is perfect for Android then Why the same code is not working while sending files from device to device.

Comment: You are only telling the same story again and again. But you should tell more and more of course. And start answering questions if someone tries to help you. You did not answer mine.

Comment: Can you please ask again, There is no exception I have found, the code runs...
Actually I mentioned a line of code at last I used to transfer file, in this line I have added the system name (userId+"/Admin") on which the PSI client is running. Admin is the user name on which the ejabbered server is running. May be that's the problem. Please ask if you wants to ask more.

Comment: If all code would run the file would be transported. Is really all code executed? Can you follow every code line step by step? Is there a connection to start with? How do you initiate the connection? Are you running an xmpp server on one of your devices?

Comment: I must say that i misread what you wanted. You do not want to send a file directly from one device to another but from device to a server first upon which the server sends it to another device. What is an ISP client?

Comment: No, the requirement is to send a file through chatting app as the normal chating application does..
anyway, I have got the solution..
I am using the below line in manifest file and the problem is solved :
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />