# Periodically send http requests or socket?

Tags: android, performance, http

I am trying to implement an android IM program,

So far i could send messages from my phone to my webserver and get responses over http but 
i am using a timer thread which runs once in 5 seconds for instant messages and an another timer to get friend requests and responses once in 15 seconds. And other timers for other tasks.

It looks fine to me but it requires lots of network connection and uses battery a lot.

I woud like to ask if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using push notifications?

Comment: Yes i did but i couldn't really find good tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of polling for messages you can use push notifications to tell your app when it should check for new messages.

http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

You could also just use one connection and xmpp.  The smack library has been used to implement chat. Take a look here.

[Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions/5487854#5487854)

Comment: Ok for instance i got my push notifications working but should i use push notifications to get every single message or should i start polling messages after first  notification?