# Sending IM to gmail account over XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp

I've recently read about XMPP and I would like to make an application which can send and receive IM messages so that I could get some experience with using XMPP. The problem is I hardly know anything about using XMPP or about using it with Android. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to use XMPP with Android.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

Answer (score 1):

Well to start with XMPP you have to

1. Install [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) (The chat server)
2. Add the [smack.jar](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) XMPP client jar into the Android app
3. Implement the PacketListener like such

> ```
> public class MyPacketListener implements PacketListener {
>
> @Override     
> public void processPacket(Packet packet) {        
>    // Write the implementation code here.
>
> //The packet contains the message and the metadata about the message.
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

4.Next you need to implement the to handle the connection fail gracefully as such.

public class XMPPConnectionFailedException extends RuntimeException {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public String toString() {

    return "The Chat server or the Connection to the chat server failed";
}
```

}

5.Next you would need the class that actually does the connecting to the XMPP server and here is a implementations

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.MessageTypeFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.PacketFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.provider.ProviderManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.PrivateDataManager;

import com.test.chat.MyPacketListener;
import com.testchat.exception.XMPPConnectionFailedException;

public class ChatUtil {

public final static String SERVER_HOST = "serverip";
public final static int SERVER_PORT = 5222;
public final static String SERVICE_NAME = "p2547738.pubip.serverbeach.com";

private static XMPPConnection xmppConnection;

public static String CURRENT_RECIPIENT_CHAT_ID;
public static String CURRENT_RECIPIENT_NAME;

public static final String IN = "IN";
public static final String OUT = "OUT";
public static String CURRENT_RECIPIENT_FB_IMAGE;
public static boolean STARTED = false;

public static XMPPConnection getXmppConnection(String username) throws XMPPConnectionFailedException {

    try {
        if (xmppConnection == null) {
            ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME);
            xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection(config);

        }

        if (!xmppConnection.isConnected()) {
            xmppConnection.connect();
        }


        if (!xmppConnection.isAuthenticated()) {
            xmppConnection.login(username, "123");
            ProviderManager pm = ProviderManager.getInstance();
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private",new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());

            PacketFilter packetFilter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);

            xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                       System.out.println("reconnectionSuccessful");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
                       System.out.println("reconnectionFailed");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {
                       System.out.println("reconnectingIn");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
                       System.out.println("connectionClosedOnError");
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void connectionClosed() {
                       System.out.println("connectionClosed");
                   }
               });

            MyPacketListener listener = new MyPacketListener();
            xmppConnection.addPacketListener(shareFareChatListener,packetFilter);


        }
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        xmppConnection.sendPacket(presence);

        ChatUtil.STARTED = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new XMPPConnectionFailedException();
    }

    return xmppConnection;

}
```

}

6.Finally you try to connect your to the XMPP server using the credentials you used to sign users up as such

private void connectToChat(final String nickname)  {
            System.out.println("Connect to chat ...");
            class ConnectToChatAsync extends AsyncTask {

```
            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Context... params) {

                try {
                    Listener.currentActivity = context;
                    ChatUtil.getXmppConnection(nickname);

                    return SERVER_SUCCESS_RESPONSE;
                } 

                catch ( XMPPConnectionFailedException e) {
                    System.err.println("XMPPConnectionFailedException : " + e);
                }

                return CONNECTIVITY_PROBLEM;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                if(result == CONNECTIVITY_PROBLEM){
//                      ApplicationDialog.showFeedBackDialog(ProjectConstants.XMPP_CHAT_FAILED, context);
                }
            }
        }

        new ConnectToChatAsync().execute();
    }
```

That should settle you Programatically, all you got to do is Setup the Openfire Environment.

### These links should help you out on that department

1. [Create Your Own Jabber-Based Server That Works With iChat or Any Jabber Client](http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/Create-Your-Own-Jabber-Based-Server_2.htm)
2. [DIY: Set up the Openfire internal chat server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/doityourself-it-guy/diy-set-up-the-openfire-internal-chat-server/1411)

Comment: Thank you very much for the implementation! I dont really understand the use of openfire though. Could I ot just use the google XMPP server and the port to establish a connection and then send messages?

Comment: Also, I have read that we need to use aSmack instead of Smack for Android. Would the smack jar work?

Comment: Did you go through the last two links and try to get an idea. I think Google has moved on from XMPP server for it's chat engine, so I would suggest you better take some time to understand the basics of what you are doing, so in no case you will be stuck if you should get into some rut.

Comment: Well I used smack.jar and it worked fine for me but Asmack should do the trick too