# Better Way to implement the chat application using XMPP on Android?

Tags: android, xmpp, xmppframework, quickblox

Hi i want to implement the Chat application in android using XMPP (To
 avoid the GCM notifications because GCM uses request response
 process).

i have done the 70 perc functionality using Smack library
 and **OpenFire** server. but after completion of these i came to know
 about the `QuickBlox SDK`. I don't know completely about that but few
 people are saying that it is good api by seeing the features..

can any one tell me that is it correct way of implementing the chat
 application using smack for xmpp . or we have any other good api which
 uses xmpp for android .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)

Comment: @Manish Agrawal http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/

Comment: @AndroidDev : the link in that page for downloading sample is broken        http://people.apache.org/~dims/android/XMPPClient.zip

Comment: @Manish Agrawal i dnt have sample code. i used that code only. copy the code and create a new project then u will get it. download the smack jar files from google.

Comment: @CoronaPintu we have installed open fire server and we have implementes server api's which will be connected to open fire server database

Comment: @CoronaPintu In Android, u can develope using smack library .. see the example. we have developed apis for our project purpose. u can do android app with our apis by depending on open fire server. https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/overview.html. check this link and follow smack api

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Stackoverflow question ["Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions) provides a good overview of XMPP client libraries for Android.

Another good resource is [xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Answer (score 8):

You can use QuickBlox<sup>1</sup> for free.

It provides XMPP server out of the box with lots of features, you can read about features there http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat

Here is an example how to start using QuickBlox with aSmack library http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample

---

<sup>1</sup>Quick disclosure: I am a developer at QuickBlox.

Comment: major issue with quickblox is that it is highly structured and greatly inflexible. You can create chat but it is not unique to your friends but just all users in the app...not good. As well, only you, the admin, can create groups which will greatly destroy the quality of your app with the need to police so many groups that only you can create

Comment: New version of QB Chat 2.0 will resolve all such issues, will be available in 2 weeks

Comment: Hi @IgorKhomenko, according to the stackoverflow rules, you are obligated to disclose that you are an employee of QuickBlox in your post. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior Please add this information.