# Which cloud based services can I use to host the XMPP server required for connecting to GCM CCS?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, xmpp, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

As App Engine does not support XMPP connections to Google's Cloud Connection Servers (CCS) for implementing the XMPP version of Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), are there any other cloud based services (preferably PAAS) like App Engine that allow hosting an XMPP server?

If not, what is the next best solution for implementing GCM XMPP for an Android app that has an App Engine based backend server side?

Comment: Is XMPP a requirement here? you can certainly talk from App Engine to GCM via HTTP (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#appengine-setup). Also, you can get this by implementing Google Cloud Endpoints that talk to GCM. see https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-addgcm

Comment: Hi Jose, I am in fact using the exact same setup that you described above but want to understand how feasible it would be to implement GCM XMPP if I require persistent connections or run into throttling issues with HTTP

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15017586/1270322) provides details on the actual limits for GCM. It looks like GCM allows you to attach up to 1,000 recipients to a single message (http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html). Beyond this, there is [Throttling](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling) on the device side. This is regardless HTTP or XMPP

Comment: This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325898/gcm-how-to-avoid-throttling) mentions that XMPP is the solution to the throttling problem. Even the documentation says that XMPP based CCS offers persistent connections at full line speed - so there should not be any throttling as in the case of discrete HTTP messages