# GCM CCS server stops responding for iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, google-cloud-messaging, smack

Using gcm ccs for real time chat for cross platform application android and iOS. Android is working fine, but with iOS after 100 messages GCM starts throttling the messages and stops responding for any.

Things tried,

1. Have set time_to_live to 0
2. delay_while_idle to false

This was supposed to minimize throttle as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325898/gcm-how-to-avoid-throttling). For testing this i am sending 1 msg / 2sec in two iOS device.

Note: GCM always throws NACK for all of the iOS messages but i suppose APNS doesn't return ACK hence the NACK for GCM. As a work around i depend on client ACK to my server instead of GCM.