# GCM send replicate topic message at short time, and gcm would delay to send?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

When I send replicate topic message(10 times per 2 second) at short time, after that it seem gcm would delay to send message no matter what I send.

The gcm format
    collapse_key:"..."
    data:{...},
    dry_run:false,

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androiddocs.com/google/gcm/adv.html#throttling

Throttling topic

and the answer could found at 
[GCM: how to avoid throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325898/gcm-how-to-avoid-throttling)