# Chat implementation Android

Tags: android, sockets, xmpp, chat

I have read many answers on StackOverflow but still found a need to ask this one.

I am making an Android Application in which i have to implement simple one-on-one chat (Just text chat).

I have implemented QuickBlox for now but I would like to implement the core integration into my application. i.e. using a web xmpp server and socket connection. As I dont want to use any third party API. For example Whatsapp has it's own implementation and doesnt use any third party API.

What all I will need for this and what is the process of implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hope this link helps you http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/

Comment: @sur007 If I have a windows server, how will I make it xmpp supporting server?

Comment: I got the link so thought it would be helpful for you. I haven't worked with chat app. Please look this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953114/better-way-to-implement-the-chat-application-using-xmpp-on-android

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily with a **Websocket server** [can be implemented with Nodejs, Ruby, Java, etc] and **WebSockets Client** implemented in android.

It is really easy to make a websocket server in nodejs and upload it to Heroku.

Access the websocket server from the android using a java [Websocket client](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync).

Comment: I have a windows server in which I have uploaded the webservices. Can I use the same server?

Comment: Yup. You can install nodejs server on windows too.

Comment: Can you help me with some implementation of Websocket server using nodejs.

Comment: http://tutorialzine.com/2014/03/nodejs-private-webchat/
This is a Nodejs Websocket Server tutorial.