# Sending text from app to friend via facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, android-listview, android-edittext, android-notifications

I have this activity with an `edittext` that the user can write a short text inside, then when done a new activity opens up with a `listview` that fetches facebook friends, i bring the text like this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNew);
            Intent intent = new Intent(NewTextActivity.this, SendActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("location", etLocation.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        };
        }
```

This is the `listvew`:

```
final OnFriendsListener mOnFriendsListener = new OnFriendsListener() {

@Override
        public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSpinner.clearAnimation();
                }
                });

            // populate list
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Profile profile : friends) {
                //profile.getInstalled();
                values.add(profile.getName());
            }
```

My next goal is to be able to make this text be sent to a friend within this `listview`, and then be recieved by that friend inside the app, and not on the actual facebook chat, but i can't really find any examples or instructions on how to do this with the facebook sdk, any tips on how i could go from here or links i could check out? :)

Answer (score 2):

You would have to keep a track of users in your own DB using their unique facebook ids. Then you would incorporate your own "chat" protocol, Such as XMPP, check this out for further reading: [Android and XMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions).

You can't just send a message using the facebook SDK is what I'm trying to say ;)