# Send message from Server to Android device and vice versa

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a chat application. But I have a few questions, which I could not solve by searching the internet.

My requests are:

- Of course I can address each device individually from my server (makes sense for a chat app)
- I can create a time delay between sending and receiving a message
- The application should not require a registration (this is not a MUST, but would be nice)

I wonder if GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) is the appropriate solution for me. I have not yet worked with it, so I would like to have some help. Will I run into troubles with this? And most important: Is a registration required?

Comment: Did you used aws S3...

Comment: Hmm... Not open source...

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will run into troubles surely, **GCM is not for creating chat applications** . You will need this [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).GCM is kind of thing used for broadcasting messages,which does not even guarantee the delivery of messages instantaneously i.e real time which you will be requiring.

SEE THIS TOO: **[Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)**

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. I was already expecting something like this. When I read the documentation of GCM, it was not clear at all.

Comment: we can create chat app using gcm See this http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142

Comment: we can create,but we should not,

Comment: we know that xmpp is best option for chatting in mobile platfrom but we have so more option

Comment: I am not afraid of learning something completely new. If XMPP is the way to go, it is definitely not bad to take a closer look at it. Thank you guys!