# Can we send the message from **Android Device** to **GCM** server?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, response, android-webservice

Can we send the message from **Android Device** to **GCM** server?

I am implementing the **Total GCM functionality** *to get message from server* and it works fine.

Now i want to **save that message response** right now i am using *separate webservice to store response to server,* 
Can i do that **using GCM instead Webservice**?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You need to create XMPP server for that. You can see brief answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236118/3210285)
You can check example of  chat [here](http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-ccs-with-xmpp/)

Answer (score 0):

GCM is only a system to deliver messages to registered devices. It is not responsible for any other activity.

If you want to store data, that will need to be on your registered device or your web service.

Comment: Yes you are right  GCM is deliver messages to registered devices , I am asking can i resend the message from my gcm register device to GCM server