# Android Client for OpenFire Server

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack, asmack

I am developing an android chat application which has to connect to the OpenFire Server running on my machine. I tried a lot of options but unable to connect even. Please help if any of you know about the same at the earliest possible. I am using smack.jar in my application. Here are the few lines from my code:

```
    String username = "test@inbasdpc06783";
    String password = "admin";



    // Create a connection
//        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
//                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);




   ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("inbasdpc06783");


   connConfig.setCompressionEnabled(true);
   connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);



    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
        Log.d("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] BEFORE Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        connection.connect();            
        Log.d("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] AFTER Connected to connection.isConnected()>>>" + connection.isConnected());            
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
```

I am getting the following error :

```
10-15 18:39:02.759: E/dalvikvm(17668): Could not find class 'javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext', referenced from method org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil.<clinit>
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.<init>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:81)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at org.apache.android.xmpp.SettingsDialog.onClick(SettingsDialog.java:51)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3538)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14330)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.DNSUtil.<clinit>(DNSUtil.java:47)
10-15 18:39:02.800: E/AndroidRuntime(17668):    ... 13 more
```

Comment: What version of aSmack are you using????

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using a Smack version < 4.1 which wont work on Android. See also [Android and XMPP: Currently available solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions)