# I want to add online capabilities to my application. How can I do it?

Tags: android, client

I have a server that I run, I'm not very good at that, but I'm making an android application, and I was wondering if there was a way to link two phones in real time where I could send a small amount of information, like a number or something. Or even something I can put on my server that would send some type of notification to the one client once the other client submits the information.

Answer (score 1):

Use **XMPP**.

To implement it no android, refer to this question: [XMPP and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392785/xmpp-and-android)

For the server, refer to this one: [Good XMPP Java Libraries for server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177514/good-xmpp-java-libraries-for-server-side) (the accepted answer list libraries to **many** languages.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try SMS. Might be a bit easier.